# What is vb.net equivalent for c# anonymous code blocks?

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

What is VB.NET equivalent for this code

```
void foo()
{
    ...
    { //anonymous code block starts here
         ...
    } //anonymous code block ends here
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent anonymous code blocks in VB.NET.

You can emulate with an if true:

```
If True Then
End If
```

Or if you don't need a block scope, you can use the regions:

```
#Region "This is the code to be collapsed"
#End Region
```

Answer (score 3):

The closest you can get is :

```
If True Then ' anonymous code block starts here
    ' ...
End If ' anonymous code block ends here
```